# auto submit and refresh once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Pls help me to modify this one I want it to submit and refresh only once not every 10sec

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    var auto = setTimeout(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 100);

    function submitform(){

      document.forms["myForm"].submit();
    }

    function autoRefresh(){
       clearTimeout(auto);
       auto = setTimeout(function(){ submitform(); autoRefresh(); }, 10000);
    }
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Use a bool variable to control your flow.

Comment: I don't have any idea can you give some codes? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local storage to check if the page is being loaded for the very first time.

```
$(function() {
    var canSubmit = localStorage.getItem("can_submit");
    if(!canSubmit) {
       // first time loaded!
       document.forms['myForm'].submit();
       localStorage.setItem("can_submit","1");
       window.location.reload();
    }else{
       //You can remove it if needed
        localStorage.removeItem("can_submit");
    }
});
```

Comment: it refresh the page and doesn't stop

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited my answer. You gotta wrap the removal of the local storage item in an else statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.location.hash !== '#done') {
        document.forms['myForm'].submit()

        window.location.hash = 'done'

        window.location.reload()
    }
}
```

This will submit the form and reload the page only once. The `hash` will check the URL if it's already been submitted.

Comment: That's because the script is executed again when the page is reloaded. As long as it's running on `onload`, it'll keep looping.

Comment: yeah that why I'm asking if it can modified to work only once

Comment: I tried it again and its working but it did not submit the form but I see the #done in the link